# My 13-month-old nephew will not sleep through the night and I'm not sure what it could be!

Tags: toddler, sleep, crying, teething, babysitting

My 13-month-old nephew has a lot of trouble settling into his sleep. His mother works an early morning shift (4:30am) that causes her to break his sleep cycle so that he can begin to be cared for by myself.

He is usually awake when she drops him off and during the exchange of care giving, he cries hysterically, but understandably so. Once he calms down and prepares for bed with me, he falls asleep. 5 minutes into his sleep, he wakes up crying relentlessly! I try to soothe him but that only seems to make it worse. So he continues to suck on his pacifier until he goes to sleep. If I move in the bed, he wakes up and it all starts over again. I literally cannot move for fear of him crying. Any movement sets him off and this happens every night.

He has his two front teeth fully grown in as well as one lateral incisor and a first molar breaking through, all on the same side. I'm not sure if this is related but he never cries in relation to teething until the time explained about... **if** that's even the reason why he's crying at all. As this is *every* night, it's very frustrating to me and I'm sure to the baby as well!

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You're in a very difficult situation. My suggestion is to move his bedtime up to 5:30 pm so that he gets adequate sleep before getting up with his mom. Of course that leaves you in a tough predicament. Ideally, your sleep schedule changes as well, or you may be forced to break up your sleep pattern.

Comment: Thankyou, I appreciate the feedback & I'll definitely be suggesting that!